# React-redux mock store providing 'undefined' values

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to mock return values of useSelector() and these test were working originally; however, some change in the repo has caused them to fail. Here are the steps I take to mock the values for the component.

Below is to mock the values that would normally be given from

```
// In Component.tsx
const requestAccess = useSelector<RootState, IGenericNetworkAction>(
   state => state.accessRequest as IGenericNetworkAction,
);
```

```
// In Component.test.tsx
const requestAccess = {
  isFetching: false,
  status: 200
} as IGenericNetworkAction
```

I then create a mockStore - along with history to wrap the component in a router

```
// In Component.test.tsx
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const history = createMemoryHistory();
const store = mockStore({requestAccess: requestAccess});
```

But upon trying to mount this component using enzyme:

```
// In Component.test.tsx
const componentRender = mount(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <Router history={history}>
       <Component />
     </Router>
   </Provider>,
);
```

I get the following error saying requestAccess.status is undefined:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

      85 |                   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      86 |                 </div>
    > 87 |                 {requestAccess.status === 200 && !requestAccess.isFetching ? (
         |                                ^
      88 |                   <p>Your request has been submitted</p>
      89 |                 ) : null}
      90 |               </Form>
```

These tests were working before so I am confused as to why they randomly decided to break and how status is undefined when I provide the necessary information to the mocked store. Am I going about this wrong? Is there another way I am supposed to provide my tests with this data?

Comment: If you are using git, consider hunting down the commit that broke the tests using `git bisect`.

Comment: @mzedeler thank you, there was a variable name change I was unaware of